# Jekyll 4.0.0 doesn't build using cache in CI

Tags: ruby, github, continuous-integration, jekyll

Hello I just upgraded my website to Jekyll 4.0.0 and it's starting to take a long time to compile. Up to 10 minutes sometimes. But when I use the incremental build locally it's able to product the compiled version in a few seconds. So I tried to cache all the Jekyll related caches I could find. I'm using CircleCI this is my config.yml

```
       - save_cache:
           key: site-cache-260320
           paths:
             - _site
             - .jekyll-cache
             - .jekyll-metadata
             - .sass-cache
```

This restores the cache folders to the repo when the CircleCI job starts. But it doesn't seem like they get reused in the compilation process. The job always takes almost 10 minutes to compile.

Am I missing a cache folder? Is there a Jekyll option I need to use? If I could get my website build/deploys down to a few seconds that would be life changing. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure you have added the restore_cache option no? https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#restore_cache

Comment: yes, I added that correctly. but I didn't include it here for brevity. the folders I specify to be cached are restored properly. but it seems jekyll doesn't use them

Answer (score 0):

The [CircleCI documentation on caching](https://github.com/circleci/circleci-docs/blob/master/jekyll/_cci2/caching.md#restoring-cache) also mention

> CircleCI restores caches in the order of keys listed in the restore_cache step. Each cache key is namespaced to the project, and retrieval is prefix-matched. The cache will be restored from the first matching key

```
steps:
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
```

So make sure to configure your `restore_cache` step, to go along with your `save_cache` step.
For instance, be aware of [the cache size](https://github.com/circleci/circleci-docs/blob/master/jekyll/_cci2/caching.md#cache-size).

Comment: yup I had the restore cache configured correctly. I didn't include it for brevity. but the packages that I specified do indeed get stored. but it seems they aren't used or recognized by jekyll as it always takes 10 minutes to do the rebuild with cache instead of 5 seconds like on my local machine